# Error:org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom

Tags: java, maven

I am running `mvn clean install`,
but I am getting the following error:

```
The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory
```

So I ran the following command again:

```
 mvn install:install-file "-DgroupId=org.mozilla" "-DartifactId=jss" "-Dversion=3.6.3" "-Dpackaging=jar" "-Dfile=/Users/Documents/costl-tablet-automation"
```

I am getting this below error:

```
standalone-pom: Error installing artifact 'org.mozilla:jss:jar': Failed to install artifact org.mozilla:jss:jar:3.6.3
```

Not sure how to solve this. Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Comment: Show your code, the project structure.

Comment: You'll need to show your POM for the first one; your command line is failing because you haven't specified a "-Dfile=...".

Comment: @AllenD.Ball what is Dfile?

Comment: Your second command line is to install an artifact (JAR) in your local repository.  You need to specify the path to your jar.  For example, if you have acquired jss.jar you'd add "-Dfile=jss.jar" to your command line.

Comment: mvn install:install-file "-DgroupId=org.mozilla" "-DartifactId=jss" "-Dversion=3.6.3" "-Dpackaging=jar" "-Dfile=/Users/Documents/costl-tablet-automation" I gave this specific command, but now the error is coming to be standalone-pom: Error installing artifact 'org.mozilla:jss:jar': Failed to install artifact org.mozilla:jss:jar:3.6.3 @AllenD.Ball